# Check whether the string has a valid word

Tags: string, format, compare, cpu-word

I want to distinguish the output responses between valid and invalid ones.
I tried checking the string with words,alphanumerics,etc..., but both the valid and invalid had these characteristics.
I will get two output responses..one is valid one and other is invalid (unreadable).

So is there any way to distinguish among these two responses.

Valid Response:

> "ABC002","01/01/2015","JNSDKJJOIJ","GREEN","000000","TEST".............

Invalid Response:

> (*^@$%$%^%^%$$FGFG#$#$%$^#$%dgfDFGERT1235434_)(p"p{_{?>:"|}{~][;/.,'

Comment: Can you further explain what a valid string is actually? Like "A valid string consists of ... and has the format ..."

Comment: A valid string just contains soe values in quotes and an invalid string contains all those that a human cannot read

Comment: So a valid response consists of:
Numbers and uppercase letters and slashes in quotes, comma seperated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if my assumption is correct, maybe this regular expression can help:

`("[A-Z0-9/]*?"),?`

This should match any quoted strings that consist of uppercase letters, numbers and slashes if they're comma seperated. If you don't need the comma seperation, just delete the last two characters of the regular expression. If you don't need the quotes too just switch their positions with the round brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using a Regular Expression

[Here is a link](https://regex101.com/r/oV9uF8/1) for a share

and here is the Regular Expression itself

```
(ABC002)|(01\/01\/2015)|(JNSDKJJOIJ)|(GREEN)|(000000)|(TEST)
```

As you define more Valid words, simply add them with the Pipe | (or) and surround the word with parenthesis.  Add the modifiers [gmi] (global, multiline, and ignore case), and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you..hope that should work..will try with regular expressions.

Comment: @user2174714: You really should avoid doing such lists with regular expressions. If you need something like this just create a whitelist and check whether your string is contained in your input. But this regular expression definitely will become a unmaintainable mess sooner or later.